# Runtime exception in recursive function

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'm getting a run time exception in a function I'm working on and I can't figure out why. The function takes two inputs a `String []` and a `String`. The exact error is:

> runtime
>   exception:java.lang.NullPointerExceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException
>   at Tourney.winner(Tourney.java:14) at Tourney.winner(Tourney.java:28)
>   at Tourney.winner(Tourney.java:28) at Tester$1.run(Tester.java:50)

**My Code**

```
public class Tourney {
    public int totalCount = 0;
      public String winner(String[] bracket, String results) {
          if (bracket.length==1){
              return bracket[0];
          }
          else{
              String [] teams = new String [bracket.length/2];
              int count = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < bracket.length/2; i+=2){
                  if (bracket[i].equals("bye")){
                      teams[count]=bracket[i+1];
                  }
                  else if (bracket[i+1].equals("bye")){//runtime exception is here
                      teams[count]=bracket[i];
                  }
                  else{
                      if(results.charAt(totalCount)=='H'){
                          teams[count]=bracket[i];
                      }
                      else{
                          teams[count]=bracket[i+1];
                      }
                  }
                  count++;
                  totalCount++;
              }
          return (winner(teams,results));
          }
      }
   }
```

**Sample inputs and results**

> bracket = {"DUKE","UCLA","bye","MIT"}
>
> results = "HL"
>
> Returns:  "MIT"

Comment: check in the line where the error happen, if is a NullPointerException is because something is null there. Do your homework. We tell you errors and you fix them in the original post what makes the answers absurd. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee:

```
else if (bracket[i+1].equals("bye"))
```

that the `ith` + `1` element exists.  Your function will eventually return an array of size `1` and therefore when it tries to access the element at index one (the second element) it will throw an NPE.

Comment: The if (bracket.length==1) {..} prevents that I think

Answer (score 0):

Without stepping through it in a debugger, I think your problem is on this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bracket.length/2; i+=2)
```

Your winner() method is called recursively, so if you're starting with an input array with 4 elements (bracket.length is 4), then the winner method will be called recursively with an input array with 2 elements after it goes through the for loop starting with the for statement referenced above.  In this second running of the method, the loop starting with the for statement listed above will execute twice.  On the second time through the loop, i will be 1, and this line:

```
else if (bracket[i+1].equals("bye")){//runtime exception
```

will attempt to access bracket[2], which does not exist (bracket.length is 2 in the recursive call - so only bracket[0] and bracket[1] are valid) and you will get your exception.